# How to find pdf of $p(r|a) $ when r=ab+n , and a,b,n are Gaussian distributed?

Tags: probability

As mentioned in the question I have $$r=ab+n$$ and $a,b,n$ are zero mean with variances $\sigma_a^2,\sigma_b^2, \sigma_n^2$ I need to find pdf of $p(r|a)$my way is :
$$p(r|a)=p(a,r)/p(a)$$ but not able to find $p(a,r)$. The answer provided is$$p(r|a)~N(0,a^2{\sigma_b}^2+\sigma_n^2)$$. **I am not able to understand how does $a^2$ come into picture in $p(R|a)$, shouldn't it be $\sigma_a^2$**

Comment: Consider $p(r|a)$ as meaning conditioned on a specific value of $a = a_0$.  Then $r$ is a simple sum of Gaussians.  (Technically, $p(r|a)$ is actually a random variable which is a function of $a$, i.e. parametrized by $a$.)